# SQL Second INSERT query with ID of first one

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I've two queries written in one time like this:

```
INSERT INTO User (usNom, usAdr1)
VALUES ('Benjamin', 'Paris');

INSERT INTO Favorites (faMovieName, usID)
VALUES ('Star Wars VI', NEED_TO_INSERT_THE_ID_OF_THE_FIRST_INSERT_QUERY)
```

Is it possible with SQL instructions or have I to get back the ID in my code before executing the second query?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First execute this query:

```
INSERT INTO User (usNom, usAdr1) VALUES ('Benjamin', 'Paris');
```

and then use `last_insert_id()` to get the id of last insert.

Now use it in:

```
INSERT INTO Favorites (faMovieName, usID)VALUES ('Star Wars VI', last_insert_id());
```

Comment: I believe you mean [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html) - `mysql_insert_id` is a php api.

Comment: @ StuartLC: Right, last_insert_id(). I edited the post. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And sorry for the duplicate, I didn't know what to search